# Import updated scripts into unity (Holotoolkit)

Tags: unity

So I've got the following problem : Developing for the Hololens means that you in most cases need this code in your project : https://github.com/Microsoft/HoloToolkit-Unity
But this code is also updating from time to time. I tried to just replace the old code with the new one which breaks all prefabs in my scenes. So is there a possibility to replace the old HoloToolkitwith the new one without breaking my scenes?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by breaks your prefabs.  Why did the prefabs break?

Comment: Missing prefab reference, for all the prefabs which are from the HoloToolKit

Comment: I see.  You replaced all of the prefabs that you were using.

Comment: Seems so yes, ut I think I found a solution. One solution which I knew about was to persist the old meta file for the prefabs which should work then.

Comment: But the solution I found just now is to create a new project with the new HoloToolkit imported and nothing else. Then export the ToolKit as package and import it in your old project, Unity will then just update everything which is new.

Comment: Well okay no it still doesnt work... the prefab is somehow there but all the script references are broken